# How do I hide html elements for x time without them taking up space?

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, invisible

I have the following page:

```html
<div class="background">
        <section class="statements">
            <article>
                <div class="article_background hidden" id="forge"></div>
                <p>
                    Greek Mythology states that Hephaistos was the god of blacksmiths, metalworking, carpenters,
                    craftsmen, artisans, sculptors, metallurgy, fire, and volcanoes.
                    During his lifetime he accomplished the creation of wonderous items; Achilles armor, Hermes winged
                    helmet and sandals, even going as far as to create automatons to work for him.
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>
</div>
```

and I want to make it invisible. I have tried with `visibility`, the problem is that it still takes up space.

I've tried quite a lot with `display` and `visibility`, but the result was never what I hoped for.

I'm trying to accomplish this in pure css

Comment: What result are you looking for? have you tried `display: none`?

Comment: You've tried quite a lot with `display`, but haven't stumbled on `none`? Really?

Comment: If you would take care to read the Question it states `hide the elements for x time` which means I want to be able to display them again, which does not work after being set to `display: none;`. I've tested it on chrome, edge and firefox. @ScottMarcus

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, I've tried it and the problem is that if you want to display it again, it doesnt work at all. I've tested it on actual Firefox/Chrome/Edge and it never worked, mostly because there is no opposite to `display: none` as there is to `visibility: hidden`

Comment: the opposite is `display: initial` or even `display: block` or `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: I did take care to read your question. I noted that you didn't show us anything that you've tried. You pose two separate questions - one in your title and one in the body of your question. If you have worked with `display`, you would undoubtedly have found that it solves the taking up space issue, so the remaining issue is simply how to time its being hidden. But you ask two questions meaning you haven't solved the taking up space part, hence my comment.

Comment: `display: initial` does not reveal the elements again.

Comment: After hiding an element with `display:none`, you can bring it back anytime you want with `display:block` or `display:inine` or `display:flex` or `display:table` or `display:table-row` or `display:table-cell` or several others. If you really had [researched `display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), you'd know that.

Comment: @Redimo yes it does. It displays the elements initial state.

Comment: It does not. I've just tested live what @ScottMarcus suggested and no option revealed anything.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved without any js trough this simple code setup:

```css
.background {
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        max-height: 0px;
}

.background {
        animation: visibility 0ms 4.5s both;
        -webkit-animation: visibility 0ms 4.5s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes visibility {
        100% {
                max-height: inherit;
                visibility: visible;
        }
}

@keyframes visibility {
        100% {
                max-height: inherit;
                visibility: visible;
        }
}
```

Due to the elements being of height 0 at the start and invisible, they occupy no space that would be represented in a scrollbar, but are still loaded on visitation.

This function then, after the set `4.5s`, removes the limitations and shows everything as it is preconfigured in css and html. Hope this can be helpfull to someone!

Comment: `@keyframes` has been standard for about 5 years now. All browsers support it. There's no reason to vendor-prefix it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need `display:none` to hide the element and `display:block` or `display:inline` (depending on what kind of element you are working with) to show it again. Or, really you can just apply `display:none` to an element and then remove that application to restore the previous style.

As for the timing part, you can hide it for a set amount of time with `setTimeout()`.

```js
let theDiv = document.querySelector("div");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  theDiv.classList.add("hidden");    // Hide the element by applying the style
  
  // Then set up a function to run 5 seconds later
  setTimeout(function(){
    theDiv.textContent = "I'm back!";
    theDiv.classList.remove("hidden"); // Remove the class that hides the element
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; } /* Will be applied for 5 seconds */
```

```html
<button>Hide the text for 5 seconds:</button>
<div>Now you see me...</div>
<div>I'll be here the whole time, but I'll move up when the element above me gets hidden and I'll move down when it comes back.</div>
<div class="hidden">You'll never see me</div>
<div>&copy; 2019</div>
```

Comment: colour me surprised, this apparentlys works in js. I'm trying it out in pure css, so that might explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: `display: none` gets triggered without a problem, but using the delay trough the animation functionality does not reveal it anymore. By exchanging the `display` functions with visibility they work, which means the logic is correct. The whole `display: none` thingie doesnt like to be changed afterwards trough css, apparently

Comment: @Redimo CSS Transitions and Animations can only work with properties that have values that can be iterated. Color values work because the CSS rendering engine knows how to get from one Hex, named color or RGB value to the next. All numbers work (obviously), and `visibility` works because, behind the scenes visibility is managed on a numeric scale. `display` doesn't work through a numeric scale and so you can't use transitions or animations with it.

Comment: Which means it's something that only works trough js, if I'm not mistaken. Because I've created an empty template with only css for the `display:none` `display: initial` and it doesnt work.

Comment: @Redimo Saying it only works with JS is not quite accurate. In the context of animation, `display` doesn't work at all (via CSS or JS) for the reason stated above. My example above is not animating `display`, it's changing it instantaneously after a certain amount of time. Animations attempt to change a value **over** a period of time so the rendering engine has to be able to know how to transition from the initial value to the end value. There are no values between `none` and `block`, it's one or the other, so you can't animate that.

Comment: Well yes, I guess the `animation` was the wrong choice of word. In the context of using css only, the animation tag is, as far as I know, the only viable choice, unless you want to use something like `:hover`. I've found the JS solution you posted (well, sort of) some times on SO already, but I was interested in a css only solution. In the meantime I found one, and wanted to answer my own question. I guess I should have stated in the question that I want to do it with CSS alone.

Comment: @Redimo Yes, especially since you tagged it with JavaScript. ;)

Comment: @Redimo You know, you could just animate the `height` and nothing else. `visibility` would be redundant.

Comment: the idea behind the visibility is just as a "2nd" measure to be safe.

Comment: @Redimo It's not needed. You're "safe" by just setting the `height`.